# jQuery UI Slider - how to use multiple sliders in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I am trying to create multiple slide bar with jquery ui slider. Problem is the value change in the last bar only when slide on the other bars.
When slide on the other slide bar value change in the last bar only.
[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/DOM_DIN/v2wvt8fm/4/)

```js
function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var w1 = 40;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var w2 = 40;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;
        
      if (r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
      
    }
    
// // slider call
var search_type = ['id1','id2','id3','id4'];
for(var i = 0; i<search_type.length; i++){
var ids = '#' + search_type[i] + '-range';
var $this = '#'+search_type[i]+'-c';
console.log($this);
console.log(ids);
$(ids).slider({
 range: true,
 min: 0,
 max: 500,
 values: [ 75, 300 ],
 slide: function(event, ui) {
  
  $(ids +' .ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min').html(ui.values[ 0 ]);
  $(ids +' .ui-slider-handle:eq(1) .price-range-max').html( ui.values[ 1 ]);
  $(ids +' .price-range-both').html('<i>' + ui.values[ 0 ] + ' - </i>' + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  console.log(ids +' .ui-slider-handle:eq(1) .price-range-max');
  //
  
    if ( ui.values[0] == ui.values[1] ) {
      $(ids+' .price-range-both i').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $(ids+' .price-range-both i').css('display', 'inline');
    }
        
        //
  
  if (collision($('.price-range-min'), $('.price-range-max')) == true) {
   $(ids +' .price-range-min,'+ ids+ ' .price-range-max').css('opacity', '0'); 
   $(ids +' .price-range-both').css('display', 'block');  
  } else {
   $(ids +' .price-range-min,'+ ids+ ' .price-range-max').css('opacity', '1'); 
   $(ids +' .price-range-both').css('display', 'none');  
  }
  
 }
});

$(ids +' .ui-slider-range').append('<span class="price-range-both value"><i>' + $(ids).slider('values', 0 ) + ' - </i>' + $(ids).slider('values', 1 ) + '</span>');

$(ids +' .ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').append('<span class="price-range-min value">' + $(ids).slider('values', 0 ) + '</span>');

$(ids +' .ui-slider-handle:eq(1)').append('<span class="price-range-max value">' + $(ids).slider('values', 1 ) + '</span>');
}
```

```html
<br>
 <input type="textbox" id="id1-min">
 <input type="textbox" id="id1-max">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div id="id1-range"></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
 <input type="textbox" id="id2-min">
 <input type="textbox" id="id2-max">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div id="id2-range" data-max="800"></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
 <input type="textbox" id="id3-min">
 <input type="textbox" id="id3-max">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div id="id3-range" data-max="800"></div>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <input type="textbox" id="id4-min">
 <input type="textbox" id="id4-max">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div id="id4-range" data-max="800"></div>
```

Comment: can you please check you console, is any error there?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of such behavior is in `var` keyword. When you assign variable `ids` in a `for` loop via `var` keyword it doesn't mean you create `i` amount of `ids`. No, sir. Actually you create one variable `ids`, which you reassign later in every iteration of your loop. This calls [variable hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) (and here is another [article](http://ignaciothayer.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/) about it).

Your `console.log` shows value of `ids` variable on each iteration. But it doesn't mean that the `slider` handler references to different values of `ids`. No again. In this piece of code: `$(ids + ' .ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min')` - `ids` references to one certain variable (one certain cell in RAM), which after all loop iterations contains `'#id4-range'` string. So you will always update the last slider.

You may ask: *"why then all sliders created and not only the last one?"*. Thats because sliders are creating just once in each iteration. You set listeners on specific node and after that they will always be attached to that node.

So, how then you obtain needed behavior? One way is to simply use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword instead of `var` when declaring `ids`. This is [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) (you better read a lot about it, it's super handy), so you may encounter with browser incompatibility ([babel](https://babeljs.io/) will help you with this). Another (**wrong, see comment below**) way is to save full selector string paths in one `array` variable, or simply keep using already existing `search_type` like so:

```
$('#' + search_type[i] + '-range .ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min').html(ui.values[0]);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/GProst/phpw3p2s/) is your example with a little modification (`let` instead `var` before `ids`)

**EDIT:**

If you want to deal with it without using `let` you should create function `createSlider`, for example. Which will do the following:

```
function createSlider(rawId){
    var id = '#' + rawId + '-range';
    console.log(id);
    $(id).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [75, 300],
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            $(id + ' .ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min').html(ui.values[0]);
            $(id + ' .ui-slider-handle:eq(1) .price-range-max').html(ui.values[1]);    

    // and so on...

}
```

Simply call this function in every iteration of the loop and pass `search_type[i]` as an argument like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < search_type.length; i++) {
    createSlider(search_type[i]);
}
```

Comment: I  mistaken=) You can't use `search_type[i]` because of same `var` keyword in `for (var i = 0; ...)`. `i` will be equal to `4` after loop ends. So here you also need to use `let` like so `for (let i = 0; ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my concise version

```
<div id="id-slider1"></div>
<div id="id-slider2"></div>
<div id="id-slider3"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[id^=id]").each(function(indx, element) {
       var id_range = $(this).attr('id');
                
       $('#'+id_range).slider({
         range: "min",    
         value: 50,
         slide: function( event, ui ) {
            //my custom code
            $('#line-'+indx).outerWidth( ui.value + "%" );
         }
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).